How to prove this inequality (swapping $x$ and $y$)?

Simulation suggests the following inequality
$$
\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x)(a-d)- y (c-d)} 
+\frac{1}{(a-c)- y (b-c)}
+\frac{1-y}{a-b}\\
>\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1-y)(a-d)- x (c-d)} 
+\frac{1}{(a-c)- x (b-c)}
+\frac{1-x}{a-b}
$$ where $x\geq 0$, $y \geq 0$, $x+y \leq 1$, $x>y$, $a, b, c, d \in [0,1]$ with $a-b>b-c>c-d>0$.

My own trial is as follows.
$$
\frac{1-y}{a-b}-\frac{1-x}{a-b}=\frac{x-y}{a-b}.
$$
$$
\frac{1}{(a-c)- y (b-c)}-\frac{1}{(a-c)- x (b-c)}\\
=-\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{\left[(a-c)- y (b-c)\right]\left[(a-c)- x (b-c)\right]}\\
\geq -\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{\left[(a-c)- (b-c)\right]\left[(a-c)- (b-c)\right]}
=-\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{(a-b)^2}.
$$ But $\frac{x-y}{a-b}-\frac{x-y}{(a-b)^2}<0$, so this goes too far.
On the other hand,
$$
\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x)(a-d)- y (c-d)}-\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1-y)(a-d)- x (c-d)}\\
\geq \frac{y^2}{y(a-d)- y (c-d)}-\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1-y)(a-d)- (1-y) (c-d)}\\
=\frac{y}{a-c}-\frac{1-y}{a-c}.
$$ But I do not know where to go.
Edit: I think this is the right way:
$$
\frac{1}{(a-c)- y (b-c)}-\frac{1}{(a-c)- x (b-c)}\\
=-\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{\left[(a-c)- y (b-c)\right]\left[(a-c)- x (b-c)\right]}\\
\geq -\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{\left[(a-c)- (b-c)\right]\left[(a-c)\right]}
=-\frac{(x-y)(b-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}.
$$

Proceeding along OP's lines.
Remark. I think we should add the condition: if $y=0$, then $x<1$.
We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x)(a-d)- y (c-d)}-\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1-y)(a-d)- x (c-d)} - \frac{-(x - y)}{a - c}\\
 ={}& \frac{(x - y)(1 - x - y)^2 (c - d)^2}{[(1-x)(a-d)- y (c-d)]\cdot [(1-y)(a-d)- x (c-d)](a - c)}\\
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that
$$- \frac{x - y}{a - c} - \frac{(x - y)(b - c)}{[(a-c) - y(b-c)][a-c - x(b - c)]} + \frac{x-y}{a-b} > 0,$$
or
$$\frac{(x - y)(b-c)}{(a - c)(a-b)} - \frac{(x - y)(b - c)}{[(a-c) - y(b-c)][a-c - x(b - c)]} > 0,$$
or
$$(a - c)(a-b) < [(a-c) - y(b-c)][a-c - x(b - c)]$$
or
$$a(1-x-y) + bxy - (1 - x)(1 - y)c > 0,$$
which is true (easy).
We are done.
